# C -error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token

Tags: c

I need help. It's displaying "error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before '=' token" 
at line 5 (at the getRandom method) when i try to build and then run it. I've gone through it several times over and over again and i can't seem to figure out what the problem could be

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

double getRandom (double min = -1, double max = 1) {
    return min + (rand() * (max - min) / RAND_MAX);
}

int totalPoints = 0;
int pointsInCircle = 0;

void *countPoints (void *X) {
    for (int i = 0; i < totalPoints; i++) {
        double X = getRandom();
        double Y = getRandom();
        if (X*X + Y*Y <= 1)pointsInCircle++;
    }
    return NULL;
}


int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    pthread_t thread;
    printf ("Enter total points for experiment : ");
    scanf  ("%d" , totalPoints);
    pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &countPoints, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread, NULL);

    double PI = (4.0 * pointsInCircle) / totalPoints;
    printf ("Approximate value for PI for total points %d is: %d " , totalPoints, PI);



    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And *where* do you get that error? On what line?

Comment: The error would also be containing the line number on which it has encountered the error

Comment: C does not take default values as function parameters

Comment: Also, are you programming C or C++? You do something which is valid in C++ but not in C.

Answer (score 4):

```
double getRandom (double min = -1, double max = 1) {
    return min + (rand() * (max - min) / RAND_MAX);
}
```

This is not C.

```
double getRandom (double min, double max) {
    return min + (rand() * (max - min) / RAND_MAX);
}
```

When you call it with no actual arguments in your code

```
    double X = getRandom();
    double Y = getRandom();
```

you should replace these calls with

```
    double X = getRandom(-1, 1);
    double Y = getRandom(-1, 1);
```

Comment: I've made the changes but when i try to run it's displaying "error: too few arguments to function 'getRandom' " at line 14. what do i do?

Comment: @Kamal Yes, in C there are no default actual arguments.  You need to pass actual arguments for each call of the function.

Comment: @Kamal If you want to call the function with -1 and 1 then do `getRandom(-1, 1);`